# Android : How can I implement user manual or app instruction on start up of app

Tags: android, user-manual

I am new to Android development, I need to show user manual like Flip-kart app on start-up of app.

Please refer the image below, You will get an idea about, What actually I want to achieve....

Is there any standard way to achieve this?

[image]

Comment: While I appreciate your friendliness in trying to help app users, I haven't seen an app do this and my first impression was, "EW!!!!  Uninstall."  I personally hate it when apps take control where I want control.  Perhaps when you find the solution you should add a "Skip the tutorial" feature.

Comment: @JeremyMiller : Obliviously, It's only for first time after app installation.

Comment: Fair enough, but don't you hate those games you install that have tutorial modes and you've played the game before on a different device and yet they don't provide a skip feature?

Comment: calm down @JeremyMiller

Comment: @preetam I'm not installing this app.  Others will be.  My point is to help SRK and his users.  There's no law saying it has to work *my* way.  Just providing other ways of thinking of things.   Keep it chill, dude.

Comment: Does anyone have found the official doc?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do the whole stuff manually.
Or use a prebuilt library called ShowcaseView.

You'll find details, code and guide here http://www.xda-developers.com/android/create-holo-themed-demo-overlays-with-showcaseview/

Comment: Just notice that ShowCaseView cannot be used when the theme of the app does not have action bar.

Answer (score 4):

Here is my suggestion

1. Get the semi-transparent images of manual pages. Keep the Images in your `res/drawable`.
2. Use `sharedpreference` to maintain the status whether this manual is shown to user on startup or not (Depending on your requirement). Check the status when the app is launched, to decide whether to show this to user or bypass it.
3. Use a `fragment` or `Activity` to display this manual images in sequence one after another.
   for this you can use `viewpager`, `swipe animation` or simple buttons.

Answer (score 1):

just use one Gallery view and skip button on it.Show that gallery on the first installation.For that you can set flag value in sharedpreference.Also shows a button for virtrual tour in Left drawer,