# Helper animations in android

Tags: android

This question might seem irrelevant but I really need help. I need to implement those floating animations that explain actions that a user can take in a particular activity. They are usually shown when an app is launched for the first time and the user can dismiss them to continue interacting with the app. I have provided 2 pictures showing what I am trying to achieve. I have searched all over the internet but what I keep getting are just gestures.shows user that they can scroll left or right[!shows the user where notifications are](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uyXqw.png) ][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uyXqw.png)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22344146/android-how-can-i-implement-user-manual-or-app-instruction-on-start-up-of-app

Answer (score 0):

You can do the whole stuff manually. Or use a prebuilt library called ShowcaseView.

You'll find details, code and guide here http://www.xda-developers.com/android/create-holo-themed-demo-overlays-with-showcaseview/

Comment: Thanks Willas I have found another rich library at github https://github.com/florent37/TutoShowcase I guess the name ShowCaseView was my biggest problem